# Flatpickr min/maxTime options not being set correctly

Tags: flatpickr

having an issue where the min or max time I set is not applied when you first open the window, or anytime I update the config dynamically after it's first created. In this example you can see it's set to be 1:00 PM minTime, but it shows 12:00 PM when toggled open. Closing the picker will correct itself to then show 1:00 PM.

```
const fp = flatpickr(".date", {
    enableTime: true,
    noCalendar: true,
    minTime: '13:00',
    dateFormat: 'h:i K',
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dkgxuw4r/

I noticed it works as expected on the doc site: https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#time-picker-w-limits, but not when I use those same exact options. So how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default hour to 13, in this way its already updated on initialization.

To do this you can use the Flatpickr config option `defaultHour: 13,`.

**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const fp = flatpickr(".date", {
    enableTime: true,
    noCalendar: true,
    defaultHour: 13,
    minTime: '13:00',
    dateFormat: 'h:i K',
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="Select Date.." class=date>
```

Comment: Hi.. do you know how to set the `minTime: current clock time?`

Comment: Like in the example above `minTime: '13:00',` . Or as shown in the documentation of flatpickr itself https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#datetimepicker-with-limited-time-range

Comment: yes but your example is fixed value. the documentation does not mention how to get current clock time. I have googling but nothings help.